# How to implement Windows workflow foundation in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation-4

I have an MVC application which build in VS2012 can I implement Workflow in this
on this project 
Which version of Workflow foundation i need to use

I dont have any hands on  experience in windows work flow foundation 
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Workflow foundation are tied to the version of .Net you use.

VS2012 can use .Net 4.5 so I would use that version of workflow in .Net 4.5.

It does depend on which version of .Net you used to build your MVC application.
You can change the version you are using in Visual Studio with Project|Properties|Applications

Note: Workflow in .Net 4 is almost the same as 4.5.
Workflows in version 3.xx are quite a bit different